# Ubuntu is very slow when launching applications

Tags: 12.10

Im using ubuntu 12.10 64bit  and i always had this problem even in 12.04 64bit.

I have tried everything since :

1. Clean install  = no success
2. Install Preload = no success
3. Change Swappiness to 10 = no success
4. Tried every version of nvidia driver = no success
5. Checked - Bencmarked the disk drive using Disk Utility = Everything fine

My pc is a Sony Vaio with Intel core 2duo 2.60 Ghz cpu and 4gb Ram. Im using ubuntu as my default OS (in his own ext4 partition + swap) and the bad thing is that when i boot in Win7 the pc is going way smoother and faster in contrast with ubuntu.

In ubuntu is like this : Boot in ubuntu , wait for let say 10 min so we are sure that everything has started and cpu load is back to 2 - 3 % , trying to start Google Chrome and counting  1 2 3 4 ..... it takes 12 to 13 seconds to load .. after this if i kill chrome and try to restart it it opens in 1 sec.

The same is happening with almost every application like VLC , Banshee , Evolution , xchat , even terminal ......

As i see that this problem always rise in the forums with no solution after all we really need some serious help.!!

Comment: hmm... I have a core2duo with 2GB of ram (yet it's running 32bit) and it works fine. Even an Atom-based netbook works bearable... Try 10.04 LTS maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem with 12.xx Ubuntu. I installed Xubuntu 12.xx on the same box and it does very well. Note that my PC had specs better than recommended for Ubuntu. If Unity is not the only preference, try [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu).

Comment: What we are facing is a bug , not specs issue.

While im having this problem my cpu is almost sleeping and my memory have more than 2 gb free....

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that the preload cache was corrupted so the deamon wasnt working.

I just deleted the cache file and everything went back to normal.

Preload deamon should be default with ubuntu. It is almost impossible to work without it

Comment: Can you explain more about your solution.